# Time Series Analysis using ts.plot and abline()

Tags: r

Please explain me which transformation should I be using in the below code to apply WN model.

Below is the code where difference is used, I did not use log() because the series is decaying :

```
data <- c(60088,48398,54687,43337,47839,43480,53297,46882,45387,47186,42794,43274,31486,29036,25242,21792,23699,19161)        

diff_data <- diff(data)       
ts.plot(diff_data)       
model_wn <- arima(diff_data, order = c(0, 0, 0))              
coeff<-model_wn$coef             
ts.plot(data)             
abline(0, coeff)
```

Please explain me two things:

1. with ts.plot and abline, the abline is not visible in the graph
2. what can I utilise using the time series analysis with the above data.

Comment: The `abline` is not visible since your coeff is equal to `-2407.471`, which is the slope of your line, that's why it is outside of the plot

Comment: Thanks @storaged my bad!! I did not notice it.  Can you share your insight what does it tell by the data.. Is the pattern good to come out of some insights. And since the pattern is decreasing , is it correct to transform it using diff... I am a newbie in time series analysis and really finding it hard to interpret patterns

Answer (score 0):

'abline' has some parameters that you can specify, for example- 
If you want a horizontal line you need to specify **h = y-value** 
If you want a vertical line, you need to specify **v = x-value**

Your plot is produced by-

**ts.plot(data)**

[image]

If you want a horizontal line in your plot, add this code after the above code-

**abline(h = 40000, lty = "dashed", col = "black")**

'lty' is for line type and 'col' is for line color.

[image]

Similarly, if you want a vertical line, replace 'h' with 'v' in the above code. But remember that the value of 'v' should be within the bounds of your x-variable values.

Hope this helps answer you're question.

Comment: can you please tell me if you see any insights from the data.

Comment: If I were to look at the plot of your raw data using ts.plot(data), I can say that the series is a trending downward. Its a very small dataset so can't comment too much on seasonality. But trend means it is not stationary and you need to difference it to make it stationary if you want to do any further modelling. I see that you did attempt to difference the series. Maybe you want to look at the acf and pacf plots at this point to make sure that your differenced series does not show a log of correlation.